# Программа не запускается без dll

Tags: c++, .net, windows, dll

Написал программу на c++. В ней есть функции: запуск программы, добавление записи в реестр, цикл и пара функций, а также несколько поключенных заголовков.

Как мне запустить уже скомпилированную программу практически на нулевом Windows (выдается ошибка о не найденом dll файле, возможно ли этот dll вместе с программой скрепить или вшить в нее) или как мне, допустим, с .net framework 4.0 опустить требования программы, скажем, до .net framework 3.0?

Comment: О какой dll речь?

Comment: MSVCP140D.dll я понимаю, что скорее всего вы предложите мне просто установить visual c++ 2015, но в данном случае это не выход.

Comment: А еще есть статическая линковка как решение проблем с vcredist...

Comment: А можно об этом по подробнее?

Comment: С чего Вы решили, что используете .Net? А если используете, то это уже не c++, а [tag:c++-cli].

Answer (score 6):

Проще всего - у вас явно никакого .NET не видно - собрать программу со *статическими* библиотеками и не мучиться.

В командной строке - ключик `/MT`, в проекте - меню Проект - Свойства - Создание кода - Библиотека времени выполнения - Многопоточная.

Тогда все необходимое из runtime-библиотек VC++ будет включено в код программы, и никакие DLL тянуть не потребуется. Размер EXE, понятно, будет побольше, чем при динамической компоновке.

Еще - скажем, если программа должна работать на чем-то стареньком типа XP, и у вас точно не используется ничего нового из API - можно указать линковщику соответствующий параметр `/VERSION` - а то последние версии VC++ ставят по умолчанию не ниже Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

`MSVCP140D.dll` является частью того, что называется Microsoft Visual C++ Run-Time Redistributable. Правильное решение этой проблемы - требовать установки этой штуки на пользовательском компьютере, или распространять вместе с программой [ее установщик](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572).

Кстати, `D` в имени означает отладочную библиотеку. Есть подозрение, что библиотека без `D` и так присутствует на любой современной винде. Попробуйте скомпилить свою программу в режиме `Release` и затем запустите на другом компьютере.

Comment: По ссылке инсталлятор для 2017 студии.

Comment: Мне он выдает `VC_redist.x64.exe`. Это не установщик студии.

Comment: redist для 2017 студии, а MSVCP140D.dll от 2015

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Он содержит в себе и её, я полагаю.

Answer (score 0):

Если программа НЕ использует .net framework и не нуждается в нём, то можно так:

1. Берёшь чистую виртуалку и копируешь на неё программу.
2. Запускаешь, она падает с сообщением, в котором указана dll, которой её не хватило.
3. Находишь эту dll у себя и кладёшь рядом с программой. запускаешь снова.

Повторять до тех пор, пока программа не запустится.

А когда запустится, у тебя будет папка с программой и пачкой dll - можно тащить куда угодно.

Comment: Так это часть решения данной головоломки, хорошо допустим что я собрал данную папку и прога запускается без нареканий, но в моем случае надо, чтобы в конечном итоге остался только 1 исполняемый файл с расширением .exe. Возможно ли так сделать?

Comment: Откомпилировать в релизе со статической версией си-рантайм. Если никакая иная функциональность в программе не использовалась, то никаких других dll и не потребуется (кроме стандартных виндосовских)

Comment: @Aleksei.C, а зачем это делать? Вполне достаточно, чтобы программа запускалась. А соединение программы с dll - это совсем отдельный вопрос (который, кстати, вероятно где-то тут есть). Он может даже winrar'ом решаться, как один из вариантов.

Comment: Долгий способ. Лучше сразу посмотреть зависимости каким-нибудь Dependency Walker.