# Как добавить зависимости в exe файл при компиляции cpp visual studio (MSVCP140D.dll)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Я делаю приложение, скажем так, для бабулек. И мне нужно вшить все зависимости в один файл, поэтому не подходит вариант с положить установщики visualcpp в папку.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/712544/195342

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Программа не запускается без dll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712544/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-dll)